# Child Constructor Not Maintaining Variables

Tags: php, class, constructor

I've discovered an odd problem with a child class that extends an abstract parent class.
I'm calling my child class like this:

```
$atts['ad_name'] = 'Test';
$atts['ad_type'] = $_REQUEST['ad_type'];
$add_ad = new wpam_ad_form( $atts );
```

My child constructor just looks like this:

```
public function __construct( $atts ) {
    parent::__construct( $atts );
    echo "<br/><br/>New window child: " . $this->ad_new_window;
    echo "<br/>Ad Name child: " . $this->ad_name;
}
```

My (simplified) parent constructor looks like this:

```
$this->ad_type = $atts['ad_type'];
$this->ad_name = stripslashes_deep( $atts['ad_name'] );
$this->ad_content = stripslashes_deep( $atts['ad_content'] );
$this->ad_image = $atts['ad_image'];
$this->ad_url = $atts['ad_url'];
$this->ad_prehtml = stripslashes_deep( $atts['ad_prehtml'] );
$this->ad_posthtml = stripslashes_deep( $atts['ad_posthtml'] );
$this->ad_new_window = ( $atts['ad_new_window'] != "" ? $atts['ad_new_window'] : 1 );
$this->ad_active = ( $atts['ad_active'] != "" ? $atts['ad_active'] : 1 );
$this->ad_archived = 0;
$this->ad_checked = 0;

echo "<br/>New window parent: " . $this->ad_new_window;
echo "<br/>Ad name parent: " . $this->ad_name;
```

The output of those echoes is giving me:

```
New window parent: 1
Ad name parent: Test

New window child:
Ad Name child:
```

I've never seen this before.  The values are being passed into the child constructor and into the parent constructor properly.  The parent constructor is setting the values properly.  Then after the parent constructor runs, the child constructor has no values in it's $this attributes.  What's causing the values to not come back from the parent class into the child class?

Comment: Is there a chance that the properties in the parent class are private?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing your property declarations in the parent class it's hard to tell. But at first glance it looks like those properties might have been set to `private`, which limits their access/visibility to that class itself (the parent) and not any class extending it will be able to access them directly.

If that is the case then your options are to set them to either `protected` or `public`, depending on your needs.

For more information on these keywords you can check the section of [documentation entitled "Visibility"](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php).